# Oracle- stored Proc

Tags: stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure. Please let me know if there is any good syntax to accomplish this: 
 I have three tables: table1, table2, table3. 

I want to join table1 to table2 but if the primary key in table2 is zero, 
then I want to join table1 with table3.

Is there a way to conditionally do this in an Oracle Stored Procedure?

Code snippet is something like this:

select t1.col1,t2.colABC 
  from 
   table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
Where 
   t1.colYear=Var_year
   AND 
    t2.colID= " select (if t1.colGroup !=0 ,select t1.colGroup. 
                         else
                            t3.colGroup)

TIA
-NewBee

Answer (score 0):

Create two queries.

The first query should join table1 and table2 only where the primary key in table2 is not zero.

The second query should join table1 with table2 and table3 only where the primary key in table2 is zero.

Union the results of both queries together.